# Api em Android para criação de ficheiros PDF

Tags: android, pdf

Quais são as api grátis disponíveis para a criação de ficheiros `pdf` em `Android`?

Comment: Posso estar errado, mas me parece ser **baseada em opiniões**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar as classes do pacote [android.graphics.pdf](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/package-summary.html) que estão disponíveis a partir do [API LEVEL 19](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.4.html) (Android 4.4).

[Exemplo retirado da documentação:](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfDocument.html)

```
 // cria um novo documento
 PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();

 // cria a descrição da página
 PageInfo pageInfo = new PageInfo.Builder(new Rect(0, 0, 100, 100), 1).create();

 // inicia a página
 Page page = document.startPage(pageInfo);

 // desenha alguma coisa na página
 View content = getContentView();
 content.draw(page.getCanvas());

 // finaliza a página
 document.finishPage(page);
 . . .
 // você pode adicionar mais páginas ...
 . . .
 // escreve o conteúdo do documento
 document.writeTo(getOutputStream());

 // fecha o documento
 document.close();
```

Caso precise dar suporte para versões anteriores do Android, uma opção gratuita é a biblioteca [Android PDF Writer](http://coderesearchlabs.com/androidpdfwriter/)

Comment: Eu não consigo fazer o download da biblioteca

Comment: @Ludger Caso esteja falando da Android PDF Writer, abra [este link](http://sourceforge.net/p/apwlibrary/code/HEAD/tree/) e clique em "Download snapshot"

Comment: Tem algum tutorial de como usar a biblioteca?

Comment: @Ludger você pode ver a documentação [neste link](http://sourceforge.net/p/apwlibrary/code/HEAD/tree/APW.pdf?format=raw)